# How can I get full resolution images from an AVCaptureSession without using the jpeg encoder?

Tags: ios, image, avcapturesession

I'm trying to save full resolution tiff files from the camera. I've seen a bunch of really helpful guides around here on capturing still images in either straight pixel data or using the jpeg hardware compressor. Thus far I'm able to capture straight pixel data in BGRA format, but I can't seem to get a sample buffer larger than 1920x1080 on a 5s. When I switch to the jpeg compressor route I get the full 5MP image.. just in jpeg format.

Here's my setup:

```
// Create the AVCaptureSession
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[self.session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];
```

and later on for output settings:

```
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,nil];
```

Or:

```
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:@{AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG}];
```

Before I ask for the sample buffer I set:

```
setHighResolutionStillImageOutputEnabled:YES
```

Then I'm using: 
`-captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` 
to get the sample buffer.

Just to finish up...
Within the completion block of `-captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:`
For Jpegs I use:

```
NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
```

For BGRA I use:

```
CFDictionaryRef metadata = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, imageDataSampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageDataSampleBuffer);
// >>>>>>>>>> lock buffer address
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);


//Get information about the image
uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

// create suitable color space
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

//Create suitable context (suitable for camera output setting kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

// <<<<<<<<<< unlock buffer address
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

// release color space
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

//Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef
CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
```

**Have I overlooked something? Everything in the pipeline seems to work and I can't find any extra settings in the Apple docs. Is there a better/different way to do this?**

**TDLR:** I can't seem to get more than 1920x1080 from a still image capture session using the BGRA pixel format output settings. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Oops! I set the class var instead of the local one and overwrote the class var later on so no session preset is used.

Code should be:

```
    // Create the AVCaptureSession
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];
```

Super simple mistake.